# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, sockets

I keep getting the debug error "cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'" in C#.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //button to start takedown
        {
            byte[] packetData = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<Packet OF Data Here>");
            string IP = "127.0.0.1";
            int port = "80";

            IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), port);

            Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            client.SendTo(packetData, ep);
        }
```

Answer (score 12):

If possible:

```
int port = 80;
```

If you cannot have an int variable you will have to parse it:

```
int port = Int32.Parse("80");
```

e.g.

```
string a = "80";
int port = Int32.Parse(a);
```

Comment: I think this should be his expected one.

Comment: Can be simplified to int.Parse("80");

Answer (score 7):

Here is the error:

```
int port = "80";
```

convert it into

```
int port=80;
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to convert `string` to `int` here:

```
int port = "80"; // can't assign string to int
```

Just pass it as int:

```
int port = 80;
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case, everyone else's answer that port needs to be of type "int" instead of type "string" is correct.  However, if you really had a string from user input, and you needed to convert it back into an int [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse) or [Int32.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse) will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

```
int port = "80";
```

is incorrect because `int` expected an integer, not a string. By using speech marks, you're provding `80` as a string, not as a integer. Simply remove the speech marks so that you're assigning the variable as an integer.

```
int port = 80;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't mention integer in "" as you have done `int port = "80";`

correct version should be  `int port = 80;`

Answer (score 0):

change
int port = "80";
to
**var** port = "80";

And
IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), port);
to
IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), **Convert.ToInt32(port)**);