# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'byte' in c#

Tags: c#

For example consider the following code:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.startUp = cmbStart.SelectedIndex.ToString();
```

in vb.net the same approach works fine but in c# it's not. Here `startUp` is user defined setting which is `type` `byte` and `cmbStart` is a `ComboBox`. What can I do to fix this error?

Comment: As the error says, the RHS is returning a string whereas you are expecting byte. Could you please paste a sample value from that combo box and also let us know what should go in startUp?

Comment: you are trying to assign a string to startUp which is of Byte datatype...

Comment: Cause `cmbStart.SelectedIndex.ToString();` equal to index value in string. if index is 0 it will return 0 as value in string.

Comment: You need to list the actual error, either selectedIndex is null (in which cas use something like String.Format("{0}", cmbStart.SelectedIndex) or cmbStart is itself not yet initialised (so null). .ToString() works for all system types that are not null. (it is possible for user defined types to throw an exception but that is a discussion for another day)

Comment: Try running VB.NET with `Option Strict On` and this conversion will also fail. VB lets you do some dopey things by default.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that `VB.Net` allow string to be implicitly converted into byte, and throw an exception if the value cannot be converted, but c# doesn't allow string to be implicitly converted.

`SelectedIndex` is of type integer, try casting it to `byte` instead of using `ToString()` method,use the following code:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.startUp = (byte)cmbStart.SelectedIndex;
```

**Useful Links**

- [Option Explicit and Option Strict in Visual Basic .NET and in Visual Basic](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/311329/option-explicit-and-option-strict-in-visual-basic-.net-and-in-visual-basic)
- [Option Strict Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx)
- [Implicit and Explicit Conversions (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kca3w8x6.aspx)
- [Conversions Between Strings and Other Types (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6hxk86b.aspx)
- [Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274555/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-string-to-int)
- [Casting and Type Conversions (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)
- [How to: Convert a String to a Number (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx)

Comment: @RubelHosen i updated my answer with some useful links about this issue, take a look

Answer (score 0):

You cann't. String type contain multiple byte 
you can choose maybe one of it's character

```
cmbStart.SelectedIndex.ToString()[0]
```

this will return first character of the converted index to string (probably not what you want).
but if you combo box doesn't has more than 256 item to select from,
you can convert the returned value for selected item to byte and store it in startup.

```
(byte)cmbStart.SelectedIndex
```

Comment: This returns a char. Even if you convert that to byte it won't be the real index but the character code of the first digit of the index. For example if item 12 is selected in the combo box, it will return the ASCII code for '1'.