# Cannot implicitly convert string to int

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a little multiplication only calculator.

I'm trying to do

```
int a;
a = Console.ReadLine();
```

and then it tell me cannot implicitly convert string to int.

I'd like it to readline my int variable and multiply it together with another int variable but its not letting me.
Thank you

```
namespace ConsoleApp9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a;
            int b;

            Console.WriteLine("Hey I'm a calculator in training and I'd like to test out my skills with you.");
            Console.WriteLine("I can only do one type of equation right now but I'm still learning");
            Console.WriteLine("What will your first number be?");
            a = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("So youre first number is ");
            Console.Write(a);
            Console.WriteLine(" Alrighty then what is your second number ?");
            b = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(a);
            Console.WriteLine("*");
            Console.WriteLine(b);
            Console.WriteLine("=");
            Console.WriteLine(a * b);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont put that sort of stuff in your title, it makes not sense, has no value, and wont get you help any faster

Comment: It's cool you're learning, and good you shared code, but you should be making an attempt to solve problems before posting, and googling "c# convert string to int" would solve this for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274555/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-string-to-int)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Method
 `Console.ReadLine();`
actually returns `string`. Whereas variable of type `int` only stores integers not string representation of integers. So you need to convert your input from `string` to `int`. Since there is no implicit conversion from `string` to `int`, so you need to convert explicitly. You can do this like this

1. `int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`  OR
2. `int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`    OR
3. `int a = (int) Console.ReadLine();`

There are other ways as well. For details visit [How to: Convert a String to a Number (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number)